# How would you prove that the Independent set is a complement of a vertex cover and vice versa

Tags: graphs, np-complete, np

I am just wondering how you would write out a proof that the independent set is the complement of the vertex cover. I know how to explain it in common language, just wondering what a more official proof would look like.

Answer (score 2):

Let $C$ be a vertex cover and $I = V \setminus C$.

**Claim.** $I$ is an independent set.

**Proof.** Let $u$ and $v$ be two vertices in $I$. Then, since neither $u$ nor $v$ are in $C$, ...

Comment: Thanks this is pretty similar to what I ended up with. I think this is an even more straightforward way of stating the proof than what I had.